# call GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading) in excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying export the excel content into a word document using a template.

There are different heading levels in the word template. I need to get the heading list so that I can insert the content from excel into the proper location. However, `GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)` is not working.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set wdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdObj.Visible = True
    wdObj.Documents.Open FileName:="test.dotx"
    Set wdDoc = wdObj.ActiveDocument
    astrHeadings = wdDoc.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
    MsgBox ("headings #" & UBound(astrHeadings)) 'correct number if in word, 0 if in excel
    wdObj.Quit
End Sub
```

I can get the list if I put the exactly same code in a word document, but the list will be always empty `(ubound(~) = 0)` if I put the same code in a excel.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are Late Binding with MS Word and hence MS Excel cannot understand what `wdRefTypeHeading` is. For MS Excel the value of that variable is `0` whereas for MS Word the value of that constant is `1`.

Try this. (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Const wdRefTypeHeading = 1

Sub Sample()
    Dim wdObj As Object, wdDoc As Object
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim astrHeadings

    Set wdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdObj.Visible = True
    FlName = "C:\test.dotx"
    Set wdDoc = wdObj.Documents.Open(FlName)

    astrHeadings = wdDoc.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)

    MsgBox ("headings #" & UBound(astrHeadings))

    wdObj.Quit

    '~~> Close and Clean Up
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, thank you so much.  it works!  sorry, i am a newbie on this vba stuff.  thanks!

Comment: Hi @user1597083.  If this post answers your question, please mark it as solution (check mark left to the post).  This is good for you, Siddharth and the whole community.